# PID controller DC motor Design using simulink

Tags: dc-motor, matlab, pid-controller

After playing the circuit, this circuit is showing the error. Tell me what is error in this circuit and what should be the P, I and D values for PID. ??? in block is not any error. It showing because i put a image in the block but the block is not considering in block.
But the question is, when i am playing this circuit at PID the connection is giving the error. Please correct this circuit at Discrete PID controller block[image: DC motor control]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller

Comment: I know about PID controller but this circuit is showing error in simulink. Please correct this circuit.

Comment: why? what exactly is the error?

Comment: I have edited the problem. Please go through that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error (ie ??? in the block) is an indication that Simulink cannot load the reference model.

This is either because

1) you do not have the required toolbox (simpowersystems)

2) you do not have the associated model reference.

As to tuning the P,I,D

For starters... forget about the D (unless further modelling shows it is needed... and it would normally be a lead-lag not a pure D).
Only you can choose the gains as you will be aware of the plant model (rpm per voltage: this would give you the P scaling) & equally the dynamic system response.

Comment: I put a image in that block but that is not showing. So, ??? in block is showing.

Comment: This is why your question is being voted down. you havn't provided any information, especially around what the real error is.

Comment: I have edit my question please read it?

Comment: Baby steps: is the SIMULINK error message: "Correct this circuit at Discrete PID controller"  or is that an order from you? if that is the error message, what is the simulator? is it a continuous or discrete?

Comment: Simulink is the package of matlab. Simulator is simulink(matlab). It is discrete.

Comment: I am aware of what they are :) I use both daily. Is the part I quoted an order from you or a 1:1 quote from an error box in simulink?